# Theorem 1 in chapter II.4 of Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

While reading Mumford's wonderful *Red Book*, I arrived to a Theorem where I don't understand the proof. So Theorem 1 in chapter II.4 says

> Let $X_0$ be a prescheme over $k_0$, let $X= X_0 \times_{k_0} k$, and let $p: X \rightarrow X_0$ be the projection. Assume that $k$ is an algebraic closure of $k_0$. Then

1. $p$ is surjective and both open and closed.
2. For all $x, y \in X$, $p(x)=p(y)$ if and only if $x = \sigma_X (y)$ for some $\sigma \in$ Gal$(k/k_0)$. Moreover, $p^{-1}(x)$ is a finite set.

Ok, I understand the proof until the "moreover statement". There, he takes a prime ideal $P \subset R \otimes_{k_0}k$ and says that it is generated by $f_1, \ldots, f_m$.

So the question is: why can he assume that $P$ is finitely generated? Is he assuming somewhere that the prescheme is noetherian?

For example, if we take $R = \Bbb Q[X_1, X_2, \ldots]$ and $P = \left<X_1 \otimes \alpha_1, X_2 \otimes \alpha_2, \ldots\right>$, where the $\alpha_i$'s are algebraic numbers, we can't find such a finite set. Even worse, we could make the set of all $\sigma$'s which leave the $\alpha_{ij}$'s fixed be just the identity, (since $\Bbb Q^{al}$ is countable) and therefore it would not be a subgroup of finite index.

Thank you!

Comment: It might just be a mistake. As a ring is noetherian if and only if all prime ideals (!) are finitely generated, the "moreover statement" amounts to $R \otimes_{k_0} k$ being noetherian. And I can't see why one should be justified to assume this, although I didn't check the entire proof. While the first statement of the theorem is definitely correct, I have some doubts about the second. (If one requires $X_0$ to be locally of finite type over $k_0$, everything clearly is fine.)

Comment: As far as I understand from the Red Book, the proof of the second statement is correct, except for the "moreover statement".

Answer (score 0):

Let $k_0=\mathbb{Q}$, $X_0=Spec(\mathbb{Q}^a)$, $A=\mathbb{Q}^a\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}^a$, then $X=Spec(A)=p^{-1}(x)$ is an infinite set.
In fact, $\mathbb{Q}^a\to A$ is integral, so Krull dimension of $X$ is $0$. Since $Q^a/Q$ is geometrically reduced, so $X$ is reduced. Assume $X$ is a finite set, i.e. $A$ has finitely many prime ideals $p_1,\dots,p_n$. Each is a maximal ideal. $\cap_{i=1}^np_i=0$.
For each $i$, $Q^a\to A/p_i$ is integral, hence an isomorphism. $A\to\prod_{i=1}^nA/p_i$  is injective, so $[Q^a:Q]=\dim_{Q^a}A\le \dim_{Q^a}\prod_iA/p_i=n$ which is absurd.